# While ignore foreach statment until while ends

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop, whitespace, fgets

Why does this code work on only the last directory listed in the file `dirs.txt` instead of working on every directory listed in that file. It seems to ignore the `foreach` statment until the `while` loop ends.

```
 <?php
    $handle = fopen("dirs.txt", "r");
    $tmpDir = "/tmp/";
    if ($handle) {
        while (($dir = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            foreach(glob($dir."*love*.mp3") as $file) {
                if (!copy($file, $tmpDir.basename($file))) {
                    echo "Cant copy $file...\n";
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
    }
    fclose($handle);
?>
```

File dirs.txt is new line separated dirs list

```
/home/mp3/
/home/music/
/etc/find/music/
```

I cant see any error, just last dir is processing. All directory is good and files exist inside, and all of them i can open manualy. If i delete /etc/find/music/ from file then /home/music/ will be done

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the content of `dirs.txt` so that we can see what might be causing the while loop to skip to the very last entry in that file?

Comment: What happens when you run the above code? Do you see the `/etc/find/music` MP3 files copied as expected, and see `Can't coppy FILE` for the MP3 files contained in the home directories? Is there a chance that your home directories should actually be `/home/username/mp3/` and `/home/username/music/` (notice that username has been added). If the home directory paths are wrong then your code won't be able to read the files from them.

Comment: I cant see any error, just last dir is processing. All directory is good and files exist inside, and all ot them i can open manualy. If i delete /etc/find/music/ from file then /home/music/ will be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that `fgets` is returning each line from your file with the newline character(s) still attached to the end of the string. But your last string (assuming you don't enter a blank line at the end of the file) would not include a newline character. If this is the case, then possibly the `glob` method is trying to find files within a directory path which is being broken into two by a newline character, something like this:

```
/home/mp3/
*love*.mp3
```

which is not going to match correctly. So the `glob` function returns an empty array, which gives the foreach loop nothing to work on, and so the `while` loop skips round to the next line of your file, hitting the same problem until the last line of the file, which does not end with a newline character.

Try inserting this as the first line of your `while` loop:

```
$dir = trim($dir);
```

That should remove any newline character and make the string suitable for use in the `glob` function.